# $K = \{A ∈ M_n(R) \mid A = A^T , \operatorname{tr}(A) = 1, x^T Ax ≥ 0 \ \ \forall x ∈ R^n\}$. Then $K$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

Let $K ⊂ M_n(\Bbb R)$ be defined by
$$K = \{A ∈ M_n(\Bbb R) \mid A = A^T , \operatorname{tr}(A) = 1, x^T Ax ≥ 0  \ \ \forall x ∈ \Bbb R^n\}$$
Then $K$ is compact.

Considering the continuous map $A \to A - A^T$, the set $K$ is the preimage of $0$. Thus $K$ is closed.

But how to show that the set is bounded?

Comment: Your argument for closedeness is incorrect.

Comment: sorry...can you please help me in that

Comment: Your set has more conditions than symmetry. You can show it is the intersection of three closed sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closedness : If $A_{n}$ is a sequence in $K$ and $A_{n}\to A$, then we can check that $A\in K$. Consider each component of matrix.

Boundedness : Every symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable, i.e. there exists $Q\in O(n,\mathbb{R})$ and diagonal matrix $D$ s.t. $A=Q^{T}DQ$. Then positive definiteness condition ($x^{T}Ax\geq 0$) is equivalent to $y^{T}Dy\geq 0$ for any $y\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, so every diagonal entries are nonnegative. Also we have $tr(A)=tr(D)$ since trace is invariant under conjugation. Conversely, we can check that any $A=Q^{T}DQ$ with $tr(D)=1$ and $\lambda_{i}\geq 0$ (here $D=diag(\lambda_{1},\dots, \lambda_{n})$) is in $K$. So we have

\begin{align}
K=\{Q^{T}DQ\,|\,Q\in O(n,\mathbb{R}), D=diag(\lambda_{1},\dots, \lambda_{n}), \lambda_{i}\geq 0, \sum_{i}\lambda_{i}=1\}
\end{align}
[Since $O(n,\mathbb{R})$ is compact](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/coursework/424/GpReps-II.pdf) and diagonal entries of $D$ are also bounded, each entries of $Q^{T}DQ$ are bounded and so is $K$.